# Java Sql Exception issue

Tags: java

I am attempting to send some data to mysql with the code listed here. 
I keep catching an exception that states "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" and I cant figure out what exactly I am missing. This is the code to my actionEvent:

```
btnLog.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            String one, two, three; 
            one = Fields.repString();
            two = Fields.shiftString();
            three = Fields.commentString();

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            java.sql.Date startDate = new java.sql.Date(calendar.getTime().getTime());

            int ID = 0;  
            int IDD = ID;
            String myDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            String myURL = "(redacted)";
            Class.forName(myDriver);
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myURL, "root", "");

            String query = " insert into reports (startDate, Representative, Shift, Comments)"
                     + " values (?, ?, ?, ?) ";

            PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            preparedStmt.setDate(1, startDate);
            preparedStmt.setString (2, one);
            preparedStmt.setString (3, two);
            preparedStmt.setString (4, three);

            preparedStmt.execute();

            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception f) {
            System.err.println("Got an exception!");
            System.err.println(f.getMessage());
        }
    }
});

reportPanel.add(btnLog);
```

**Update**

Changed `System.err.println(f.getMessage());` to `System.err.println(f);` and the error message is:

> Got an exception! java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: That is the only thing that netbeans is saying to me. This is the first time ive used netbeans in a long time though So i may be forgetting how to view something.

Comment: That's because you don't have your driver jar (that contains com.mysql.jdbc.Driver class) present in the classpath. On a side note, never use System out or err, instead use logging frameworks like log4j/lj4j2/logback etc.

Comment: SMA, I thought I had done that, how can I confirm/add it to the classpath? Also why is out/err a bad habit to use?

Comment: I got it guys. Quick google search for classpathing and it worked like a charm. Thanks for getting me on track!